# Spinnaker with Halyard from Helm Chart has missing aws cli

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I create Spinnaker from Helm Chart (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/spinnaker).

Then I want to add ECR to my Spinnaker. I connect to haylard:

```
kubectl exec -it -n spinnaker spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0 bash
```

Then I put this command:

```
hal config provider docker-registry account add ecr-registry --repositories REPOSITORY_NAME --address https://ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com --username AWS --password-command "aws --region REGION ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 -d | sed 's/^AWS://'"
```

But on this spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0 aws CLI is not installed. So this ECR cannot be added.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to this? Looks like the AWS cli is included already however doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

AWS cli is not installed on halyard by default I believe. If required, you can access the container as root and install it. However, if you are trying to configure ECR with spinnaker using --password-command, you won't need aws cli to be installed in halyard pod. Hope this helps.

Comment: What does the --password-command look like? Won't that need to invoke the aws cli?